# Vowel Counter Broken in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am struggling to get this vowel counter to work. I should be able to input the file ( am I doing the inputting right) should read the text document(which it doesn't) and then count the vowels. Also, if I could I could get it to count the number of words but this isn't necessary.
The error code say that the variable myline is already declared in the current block. ?? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim vowel As Integer = 0
        Dim Text, myline As String
        Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader
        objStreamReader = New StreamReader("H:\vowelcounter.txt")
        Dim myline = objStreamReader
        Text = objStreamReader.ReadLine()

        Do While Not Text Is Nothing
            Console.WriteLine(text)
            For x = 0 To Text.Length
                If x = "a" Then
                    vowel = vowel + 1
                End If
                If x = "e" Then
                    vowel = vowel + 1
                End If
                If x = "i" Then
                    vowel = vowel + 1
                End If
                If x = "o" Then
                    vowel = vowel + 1
                End If
                If x = "u" Then
                    vowel = vowel + 1
                End If
                If x = "A" Then
                    vowel = vowel + 1
                End If
                If x = "E" Then
                    vowel = vowel + 1
                End If
                If x = "I" Then
                    vowel = vowel + 1
                End If
                If x = "O" Then
                    vowel = vowel + 1
                End If
                If x = "U" Then
                    vowel = vowel + 1
                End If
            Next

        Loop
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: `x` will never equal a character as it is an integer of between 0 and `text.length`.

Comment: You are also using an object that implements `iDisposable` and you have not closed it at the end of your code. You need to use the `Using` statement.

Comment: Your `Do While Loop` will run infinitely so long as `Text` is Nothing at execution of the loop iteration as it is not changed throughout the loop.

Comment: You could also use `vowel += 1I` instead of `vowel = vowel + 1`. The way you have that statement will work fine, however the shorthand is easier to read in most situations

Answer (score 2):

> The error code say that the variable myline is already declared in the
>   current block.

Yes, it is:

```
Dim Text, myline As String   ' <----- HERE
Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader
objStreamReader = New StreamReader("H:\vowelcounter.txt")
Dim myline = objStreamReader ' <----- and HERE
```

So rename the first string variable or the `StreamReader` (why do you need two for one at all?).

You could achieve the vowel-counter much more easier:

```
Dim text As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("H:\vowelcounter.txt")
Dim vowels = From c In text Where "aeiouAEIOU".Contains(c)
Dim vowelCount As Int32 = vowels.Count()
```

You can get the word-count in this way:

```
Dim words = text.Split()
Dim wordCount As Int32 = words.Length
```

This assumes only spaces, tabs or new-line characters are delimiter. If you need other characters as well:

```
Dim wordDelimiter As Char() = {" "C, ControlChars.Tab, ","C, "."C, "!"C, "?"C, _
";"C, ":"C, "/"C, "\"C, "["C, "]"C, _
"("C, ")"C, "<"C, ">"C, "@"C, """"C, _
"'"C}
Dim words = text.Split(wordDelimiter, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to understand this before progressing onto harder stuff. Which one do I need to delete ? As you can see I am inputting a file so do I input the myline as string.?

Comment: Which one do I delete. I delete the firs myline as string and It now comes up with this : An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Conversion from string "a" to type 'Double' is not valid. It also says split is not a member of text.

Comment: @user5423489: it depends on you. The `Dim myline = objStreamReader` is clearly wrong. Why should a `StreamReader` be called `myLine`? It all about readability. Have you seen my simpler approach?

Comment: This is why I am confused I don't know which one to use to count the vowels in the document I am inputting

Comment: You can drop the `Dim myline = objStreamReader`

Comment: @TimSchmelter No mention of `x` never being a character as it is the counter for the `For  Next` loop? No mention of using an `iDisposable` object without `Using` or closing the object? How about that the `Do While Loop` will run infinitely because `Text` is never changed?

Comment: @вʀaᴎᴅᴏƞвєнᴎєƞ: there are probably even more things to correct. But i have suggested a three line approach which fixes all. I cannot always correct everything. If you try to mention everything this often pollutes an answer so that neither OP nor futer readers will understand what was actually causing the main issue.